# Remove dots from button label

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a button and i give the label value dynamically.  And button width=100;

If i give `btn.label = "Good Morning Have a nice day";` it shows

[image]

But i need to remove the dots. and i have a different function to marquee.

```
var t:Timer = new Timer(500);
btn1.label += "  ";
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,function(ev:TimerEvent): void
{
  btn1.label = btn1.label.substr(1) + btn1.label.charAt(0);
}
);
t.start();
```

i have another button as btn2.

Click event on btn2 calls the above code and the label text start to move towards left. But i need to remove the dot.

any help???

Comment: got my answer .. But if any body want to post your answer you can share your answer thank you

Comment: If you figured it out, please post it as an answer and mark it as correct when you are able to (usually 2 days after posting the question if answering it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer.

```
private var str:String;
str = "Text To Display" + "  ";
str = str.substr(1) + str.charAt(0);
btn1.label = updateLabel(str);

private function updateLabel(str:String):String
{
   return new String(str).substr(0,10);
}
```

it works for me. if any one have any other solutions then please share your views. Thank you